# Java InputMismatch Exception error

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a text file named Marathon_Data.txt and when I run, this error shows up:

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"
We had not yet learned how to handle exceptions, so thus far have only been using throws IOException. Would this be causing the issue?
 Thanks

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Marathon 
    {
    final static int SIZE = 5;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
   int miles[][] = new int[SIZE][7];
   String names[] = new String[SIZE];

   //variables
   int i=0, j=0;
   int totalWeek = 0;
   double average = 0.0;


   //opening file

   File file = new File("Marathon_Data.txt");
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

   while (inputFile.hasNext())
   {
     j=0;
     names[i]=inputFile.next();
     while(inputFile.hasNext())
     {
      miles[i][j]=inputFile.nextInt();
      j++;
     }
     i++;
   }



   //Display total miles ran in each week by each runner and their average
   System.out.println("Name          Total Miles       Average");
   for(i=0;i<miles.length;i++)
   { 
     System.out.print(names[i]);
     for(j=0;j<miles[0].length;j++)
     {
     totalWeek +=miles[i][j];
     }
     average = (double)totalWeek / miles[0].length;
     System.out.printf("%d\t\t%.2f\n", totalWeek, average);
     totalWeek = 0;
  }

  }//end main method       

 }//end class
```

Comment: This error presumably occurs when you run, not compile the code.

Comment: it's more important to know the cause of it rather than catching the exception. debug your program step by step and see the data being read at runtime.

Comment: How many names are in the file? You probably want to stop the inner loop before it reaches the next record?